# Social Login Sub Domain

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use external logins in an ASP MVC project which should be shared across sub domains. Right now i have managed to set the cookie domain for username/passord login option and it works. For this I have set the following in Startup.Auth:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
   AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
   LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
   CookieDomain= ".example.com",
});
```

Now if i am logged in to `www.example.com` i am also logged in to `sub.example.com` etc etc.

I am trying to do the same for social logins ie. `Facebook` and `Instagram`.

Is there a way to alter the cookie domain name for external login?